# "FirebaseCore" version not compatible in react native project

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods

In my react native project I started getting an error after I have tried to install the module firebase/crashlytics. I get the error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
  In Podfile:
    FirebaseCore

    FirebaseStorageInternal was resolved to 9.6.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)

    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 16.4.3, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.1.0) was resolved to 10.1.0, which depends on
        FirebaseCore (= 10.1.0)
```

What I tried:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
pod deintegrate
pod install
pod update
pod repo update && pod install --repo-update
yarn install
```

nothing helped. I think before I had the problem the firebase/core version was 8. How can I change the 10.1.0 version? How is this pod installed, I don't see it in the pod file.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I just added the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`FirebaseStorageInternal` has been removed from Firebase 10.x and should not be included in Podfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by downgrading all firebase module in package.josn to the version 14.12.0

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "14.12.0",
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it, i just did that and I get this error in the Expo build process, any clue?

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 9.5.0) was resolved to 9.5.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 9.5.0)
    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 14.12.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.15.0)